# Whats "now" in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to set the default value to `now` for my datetime field in SQL Server, what is this?

I've tried `NOW()`

Comment: I'm sure you would find the answer to such trivial questions also by using your favorite web search or by looking at the MSDN documentation. The second result by searching for "MSSQL now()" using Google already leads to a stackoverflow question with exactly the answer that you need.

Comment: You **gotta** learn to consult the [Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx) for those most basic questions like this.....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MSDN answers this at length http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188751.aspx

The link also includes the various ways to get just the time and just the date which is sometimes what people are really after when they ask when is Now()

```
SELECT SYSDATETIME()
    ,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
    ,SYSUTCDATETIME()
    ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ,GETDATE()
    ,GETUTCDATE();
/* Returned:
SYSDATETIME()      2007-04-30 13:10:02.0474381
SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()2007-04-30 13:10:02.0474381 -07:00
SYSUTCDATETIME()   2007-04-30 20:10:02.0474381
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  2007-04-30 13:10:02.047
GETDATE()          2007-04-30 13:10:02.047
GETUTCDATE()       2007-04-30 20:10:02.047
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways of doing this.

```
SELECT GETDATE(),
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, /*ANSI SQL equivalent of GetDate*/
       SYSDATETIME() /*2008 - Returns datetime2 with greater precision*/
```

Answer (score 1):

It is [GETDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx):

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS X
```